# Spring Data JPA query fails after 17 minutes on prod db but ok on test db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a very strange problem with a Spring Data JPA Repository interface method.

The method is quite simple:

`List<Records> findByClientNameIgnoreCaseContainingAndRecordDateBetween (String client, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws DataAccessException;`

This works perfectly fine on the test db, but on the production database the application starts to execute this query and then after 17 minutes it just throws this exception:
`ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Closed Connection: next`

Here is the full stack trace:

```
12:17:53.728 [main] ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.record.app.Application.main(Application.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at $Proxy81.findByClientNameIgnoreCaseContainingAndRecordDateBetween(Unknown Source)
    at com.record.app.reports.batchestransactions3.content.BatchAndTransactReportContentFactoryNewImpl.getTransactionsListByName(BatchAndTransactReportContentFactoryNewImpl.java:386)
    at com.record.app.reports.batchestransactions3.content.BatchAndTransactReportContentFactoryNewImpl.findTransactionsByName(BatchAndTransactReportContentFactoryNewImpl.java:368)
    at com.record.app.reports.batchestransactions3.content.BatchAndTransactReportContentFactoryNewImpl.prepareForCl(BatchAndTransactReportContentFactoryNewImpl.java:108)
    at com.record.app.reportfactory.ClReportFactoryImpl.prepareFillAndCreate(ClReportFactoryImpl.java:78)
    at com.record.app.service.DBReportProcessService.process(DBReportProcessService.java:62)
    at com.record.app.builder.ReportBuilderImpl.startBuildingReport(ReportBuilderImpl.java:226)
    at com.record.app.builder.ReportBuilderImpl.processReports(ReportBuilderImpl.java:119)
    at com.record.app.builder.ReportBuilderImpl.buildReport(ReportBuilderImpl.java:93)
    at com.record.app.ReportGenerator.run(ReportGenerator.java:61)
    at com.record.app.Application.run(Application.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2613)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2593)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2422)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2417)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1339)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
    at $Proxy99.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection: next
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:968)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2610)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

One very interesting thing is that I have a `removeAbandonedTimeout` set for `30` seconds, and the application is still working for 17 minutes trying to execute the query.

Comment: Is there a potentially different code path in prod that could be using a closed `ResultSet`? Somewhere nearby `BatchAndTransactReportContentFactoryNewImpl#getTransactionsListByName`

Comment: @ptomli can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Googling for the root cause `Closed Connection: next` suggests that it's a result of operating on a closed `ResultSet`. The stacktrace seems to point to somewhere near that code reference, being the only non-Spring-ish package. I'd normally start looking there. Any chance of the connection being closed by a pool/manager/blah (eg: lack of activity)? Is the query near there likely to run a lot longer in production than dev?

Comment: I doubt it's anything to do with Hibernate or JPA. I'd turn on logging to see exactly what SQL statement is running, then give that to a DBA and get them to profile the execution of the statement and see why it's taking so long.

Comment: @PaulNUK could it be that JPA isn't using the correct db index?

Comment: @ptomli it should display a timeout exception if that's the case. This is another case. It seems as if the query is continuing execution as if it is still searching.

Comment: I'm thinking if this has to do with anything `IgnoreCaseContaining`

Comment: @DenissM.JPA just generates SQL. It's up to the database to decide on what index it needs to use. Depending on JPA provider (Hibernate/Eclipselink etc) there are ways to specify query hints, but your best bet is to get a dba to see what is going on on the db side.

Comment: You won't believe it guys, but removing `IgnoreCaseContaining` from the JPA repository method solved this problem. And now I don't have to speak to the DBA, which is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `IgnoreCaseContaining` from the repository query method solved the issue.